# Microsoft Graph API for external users

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

In my application, I need to get user data like user name and email, also using API, I use [find meeting time](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/findmeetingtimes-example) and [create calendar event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/calendar-post-events?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http). Users those will use application will not be in my AD group.

Is there some scenario for making API workable for external users?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are certain limitations and for guest users in the organizations:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/users?view=graph-rest-1.0#user-and-group-search-limitations-for-guest-users-in-organizations
[image]

For inviting or adding the Add a guest user and send an invitation please refer :https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/external-identities/b2b-quickstart-add-guest-users-portal